# How to find the best population (gStar)

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, evolutionary-algorithm

How to find the best population (gStar) from random population, and then print weights from best population, i want to optimize the best population using FPA, i'm sorry cz i'm newbie

```
#FP Parameters
num_train = len(X_trainNorm)
input_dim = windowSize
output_dim = 1


popSize = 5

#Model of JST
def buildModel(hidden_dim):
    np.random.seed(7)
    pop = []
    for i in range(popSize):
        W1 = np.random.randn(input_dim, hidden_dim) / np.sqrt(input_dim)
        b1 = np.zeros((1, hidden_dim))
        W2 = np.random.randn(hidden_dim, output_dim) / np.sqrt(hidden_dim)
        b2 = np.zeros((1, output_dim))
        pop.append((W1, W2, b1, b2))
    return pop

buildModel(10)

#Find the best population
def gStar(Weight1, Weight2, bias1, bias2):
    z1 = X_trainNorm.dot(Weight1) + bias1
    a1 = np.tanh(z1)
    z2 = a1.dot(Weight2) + bias2
    target = np.reshape(y_trainNorm,(-1,1))
    error = 0
    error = abs(z2-target)
    tot_error = sum(error)
    print (tot_error)
```

Comment: Hi there: what do you mean by the "best" population?

Comment: like fitness or minimum error from some vector/population